# c++ copy a value to one string and it populated another

Tags: c++, memory

I have a function in which I populate some string variables. problem is I set 6 vars with source and destination path,names and extensions, I set a further two variables and one of the file varaibles changes as well.

```
    lAppendStr.assign(ID_MONGODB_APPEND); // "smallfiles=true\0";
    lSearchStr.assign(ID_MONGODB_APPEND); // "smallfiles=true\0";
    lSrcPath.assign(ID_MONGOODB_PATH); //  "/etc/\0" ;
    lSrcName.assign(ID_MONGOODB_NAME); //   "mongodb\0";
    lSrcExt.assign(ID_MONGOODB_EXT); //     ".conf\0";
    lDestPath.assign(ID_MONGOODB_PATH); //  "/etc/\0";

    lDestName.assign(ID_MONGOODB_PATH); //  "mongodb\0";

    lDestExt.assign(ID_DEFAULT); // "def";
```

when .def is assigned, lAppendStr is also populated with .def

All vars are strings and initialised with "" the ID definitions are terminated with \0 but only as a clutch at straws operation.

I have tried using the string values instead of the ID, and moving the list around changes the assignment results but the variables are still getting cross contaminated.

This is obviously part of larger code, but I guess in my mind is a memory boundary problem. I also posted an issue regarding a call to construct a class, which feels like a it could be in the same vein.

This is LINUX os developed on a MacBookair, in an eclipse oxygen dev editor environment.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If `lDestExt.assign(ID_DEFAULT); // "def";` is actually using a non null terminated string then that is undefined behavior.

Comment: Found the answer, a call to a class destructor was causing the problem in the function.

Comment: resolved by changing FileHandler doc to FileHandler *dbc = new FileHandler;

Comment: Sorry Filehandler dbc

Comment: This was causing some undefined behaviour in memory